# Add/Remove Class of a link with jQuery inside a nav ul li h4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I have 5 a link items in a row, encapsulated within a h4 and the h4 within li element and the li within ul which it's finally nested in a nav element.

At the moment, the role of a (thanks to a very helpful example that I found here) when clicked is to change the content of the divs (that contain images and text).

What I would like to do in addition, is that when you click the link and the content changes, I would like a link to receive the "active" class, which has white color and certain other css attributes.

```
<script>      
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  }); 
</script>
```

**the function that swaps the content**

```
<nav id="nav2">       
  <ul  class="tabz">
    <li><h4><a href="#tabs-1" class="active">Szenario 1</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a href="#tabs-2">Szenario 2</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a href="#tabs-3">Szenario 3</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a href="#tabs-4">Szenario 4</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a href="#tabs-5">Szenario 5</a></h4></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When the page loads, everything displays correctly. When I click the second link I would like the "active" class to be removed from first link and go to the sencond.
(The css of the active class is just some color and border differences.)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is the `tabs()` method from jQuery UI? If yes then use the `.ui-state-active` class in your CSS to style the active element. If not... I'm almost sure whatever plugin you used manages the class names and maybe even can be configured by passing some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[href^="#tabs"]').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active').parents('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

With the markup you have, the clicked `a` element won't have any sibling, but its `li` parent will, so this code will work as expected, see here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n3t4Y/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it's a css issue now, as I removed all the css and the answer works.

Comment: Add the CSS here and to the jsfiddle so that we can help you more (if needed).

Comment: Thank you, I'll make a very narrow research and I'll let you know soon :)

Answer (score 3):

Attach handler for those `anchor` tags by using the `attribute starts` with selector, since you are having `href` with same beginning. And by using the `$(this)` reference set the active class and remove the active class from all of its anchor siblings.

Try,

```
$('[href^="#tabs"]').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).closest('.tabz').find('a').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your swift reply. Code looks really good but it won't work :/

Comment: @user3153643 Are you facing any problems.?

Comment: This solution should add `.active` to links after clicking on them, but won't remove the class from other links, because `.siblings('a')` will return an empty collection (there's only one `<a />` element per parent).

Comment: Here is a screenshot:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ven7lcovy92ujaq/Screenshot%202014-01-02%2014.00.00.png)
I press the second link but the class change wont happen.

Comment: @pawel Great.! I have not seen that.! Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Still no go. It is almost certain tho, that there is a conflict within the css. If I remove all the stylesheets then it works... However I cant see any conflict with the a links or lists, everything is nested.